# Changing timezone of server using cPanel / WHM

Tags: php, timezone

I have changed time zone of my server to `Asia/Kolkata` in WHM by going to the following path:

`Home > Server Configuration > Server Time`

But still my website is showing timezone as `America/Denver` when I check it using PHP.

I have pasted the following code in `test.php` file in `public_html` directory of my domain.

```
<?php
     echo 'Time zone is: '.date('e');
     echo 'Time zone is: '.date_default_timezone_get(); 
?>
```

I have 3 websites on my server, all of them having the same problem. **What should be done to get the time zone same as WHM in all websites?**

Two solutions can be to set a default timezone using `PHP` or `.htaccess`. But I want to know why default timezone is not showing as `Asia/Kolkata` even if server timezone is set to `Asia/Kolkata` in WHM.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your php.ini (you can look for it under "PHP Configuration Editor" in WHM or manually at `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`) and set `date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"`